# Js to Python file

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, webdriver

I'm trying to decode 'base64' a .crx file by javascript and then use it on python file

the crx is decoded but i don't know how to import it to my python file

**my js file : extension.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var File = fs.readFileSync('C:\\Users\\SAMSUNG\\Dropbox\\SB.crx', 'base64');

console.log(File);
```

**my python file : DO.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
capabilities = {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "version": "81.0",
    "enableVNC": True,
    "enableVideo": True,
    "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": ["disable-infobars", "start-maximized"],
         "extensions": []}
}
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://Selenoid/wd/hub",
                          desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

**I want to put the value of "File" (in js) into "extensions": [] so my python file become like this "extension": [File]**

Comment: CRX files are using zip compression, not base64.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, i just want to import the var File from my Js file to my Python file